# camera calibration for partial occlusions

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration, occlusion

I hope you guys understand me this time around, it seems every question I ask is not real or vague or something.

I am using OpenCV and C++ to create a 3D image reconstruction program.

I have been able to implement the camera calibration aspect, but is not robust to partial occlusion, this is where I need your expert opinion on this.

When there is occlusion of atleast one corner, no corners are detected, so I want help as to how I can detect corners with partial occlusion?

Comment: You might want to extend your question with additional details, as we do not know what kind of algorithms you are using, how you implemented them in your code, etc. Telling you what is going wrong without these details is very hard...

Comment: I am using the function findchessboard corners algorithm to detect corners but the problem is that it doesn't deal well with partial occlusion, that it will detect nothing if there is any occlusion. Algorithm is that i detect the corners of a chessboard without occlusion and store the corners in a vector. Now i need to use those corners to develop a bounding box made up of voxels with an object placed on the board but placing object on board occludes the corners and therefore no corners detected.